# Problems using Firebase in Library Module: Uknown property 'LibraryVariants'

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I'm trying to add Firebase to my project, but my project is a little special. Firebase will be used in a library module of my project, so it will not be on my app module.

I'm following the manual process of adding firebase from the guidelines, but always I get this error:

> Unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

I'm adding this on my project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
  }
}
```

And this on my library module gradle file:

```
    ...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error appears when trying to synch my project. I tried also with the last gradle plugin. Also I tried adding the plugin in my app module with same result. I'm using Android Studio 3.0.

What is producing this error? Maybe Firebase is not compatible with library modules?

PS: I'm compiling with SDK level 23:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
```

Note: I know that there are questions answered in Stack Overflow about *LibraryVariants*, but those questions do not apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

The google-services plugin is not intended to be used on a library module.  It's only for app modules.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) says in step 1:

> Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
>
> Note: Android Studio projects contain a top-level build.gradle file
>   and a build.gradle file for each module. Be sure to edit the file for
>   your application module. See Building Your Project with Gradle for
>   more information about Gradle.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) says:

> This step requires that the apply plugin:
>   'com.google.gms.google-services' line be at the bottom of your
>   app/build.gradle

And also:

> The google-services.json file is generally placed in the app/
>   directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module).

Comment: So it is not possible to use Firebase in a Library? Do you have a link with that documented?

Comment: Also, this library module is being used on my project, so its my application.

Comment: Updated with doc references.

Comment: It doesn't matter where your library project is being used.  On the other hand, think about what might happen if you imported two library projects, each with a Firebase app configured.  What would happen?

You can certainly import firebase dependencies into a library project, but Firebase as a whole needs a single configuration for a single app.  If you don't want to default method of configuration, you can always initialize it manually as needed in your app. http://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

Comment: thank you but in that quotes i can't see any line that tolds that you can't use firebase in a Library module... they are just telling how to add it on an app module.

Comment: The quotes are all referring to your "app" directory and your "application" module.  This is specifically leaving out library modules.